# Send Emoticons over LinkedIn share API

Tags: linkedin-api, utf8mb4

I've tried to post utf8mb4 chars - like  - via share API to LinkedIn. But I always get 'illegal characters in XML' as response. Already tried to 'escape' it with CDATA, but it doesn't help.

When posting those chars in LinkedIn directly, it works. :-/

Any idea? Posting without those chars works without problems.

Comment: Write a bug report with LinkedIn about the Share API.

Comment: Haha... I still wait for an answer I asked about 2 years ago. ;o) LinkedIn support isn't the best ....

Answer (score 1):

For me, posting utf8mb4 characters (like ) works fine if you use the json endpoint/format.

However, if you're posting XML, you need to convert them to their html entity values (e.g. &#128513;)... then it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, LinkedIn ***only*** supports the `url` parameter in its share URL.  So, you'll only be able to have a share button that shares a URL, not text.  Like this..

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check us out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]